# How to Filter Nested table with repeat region

Tags: php

I have two tables that are related in my MySQL database, tblcomments_main & tblcomments_sub. I want to nest tblcomments_sub into tblcomments_main and filter it with CommentID. Please help me achieve this.

Comment: Please read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue myself again so never mind. If any one has the same issue, please let me know and i will help you out. Thanks.